# How can I modify an InDesign's document textFrame created from InCopy?

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, adobe-incopy

I have an InDesign file that I'm trying to script through but I'm running into an issue.  I believe a portion of the document's content was created from InCopy because when I try to modify that text frame after scripting through the pages I get a:

[image]

I do not have access to InCopy and I've tried overriding the InCopy frames by exporting the INDD file to an IDML file then bringing it back in but I'm unable to bypass InCopy.  When I research the site the closest question I was able to find was [How to script InDesign/InCopy to “Check In” and “Check Out” textFrames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992465/how-to-script-indesign-incopy-to-check-in-and-check-out-textframes) but when I try to implement `checkOut()` onto the selection I get an error so I researched and ran across:

- [How to use app.selection[0] for scripts in Adobe InDesign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908569/how-to-use-app-selection0-for-scripts-in-adobe-indesign)
- [Indesign script (Javascript) to return/select words around insertion point](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/47366/indesign-script-javascript-to-return-select-words-around-insertion-point)
- [SELECTED TEXT FORMATTING](https://indesignsecrets.com/topic/selected-text-formatting)

but I am still unable to insert on the selection text frame.

### Trimmed down code

```
function run() {
    throw new Error( "Script has run into an error" ); 
}  
run.error = null;  

try {  
    app.doScript( somePages ); 
    if ( run.error ) { 
        throw run.error; 
    }
}  catch(e) {  
    alert( e );  
} 

function somePages() {
    var allPages = app.documents[0].pages.everyItem().getElements(),
        items = app.activeDocument.allPageItems,
        pageCount = allPages.length;

    for ( var x = allPages.length-1; x >= 0; x-- ) {
        if ( allPages[x].textFrames.length != 0  && items[x].locked == false ) {
            app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
            app.select(allPages[x].textFrames[0].insertionPoints[0]);
            app.selection[0].contents= "foobar" + allPages[x].name;
        } 
    }
}
```

How can I script against a textframe to add text created from InCopy that will allow me to run through the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in a case of a text frame, what has to be checked out is the story.

```js
function run() {
    throw new Error( "Script has run into an error" ); 
}  
run.error = null;  

try {  
    app.doScript( somePages ); 
    if ( run.error ) { 
        throw run.error; 
    }
}  catch(e) {  
    alert( e );  
} 

function somePages() {
    var allPages = app.documents[0].pages.everyItem().getElements(),
        items = app.activeDocument.allPageItems,
        pageCount = allPages.length;

    for ( var x = allPages.length-1; x >= 0; x-- ) {
        if ( allPages[x].textFrames.length != 0  && items[x].locked == false ) {
   app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().checkOut();
            app.activeDocument.pageItems.everyItem().locked = false;
            app.select(allPages[x].textFrames[0].insertionPoints[0]);
            app.selection[0].contents= "foobar" + allPages[x].name;
        } 
    }
}
```

**app.activeDocument.stories.everyItem().checkOut();**

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still not working.  I still get the same issue as mentioned above, with the select and it throws an error.  The exact error: "value for parameter 'selectableItems of method 'select'.  Expected Object, Array of Objects, NothingEnum enumerator or SelectAll enumerator, but received nothing.'"

Comment: FWIW you don't need to select object in order to change contents. try to remove the line.

Comment: if I did that then I cant insert text into the frames which is what I'm trying to do

Comment: I don't think your issue is related to that call as you can edit object properties without the urge of selecting it.